# Is Forms Authentication worth learning? Could it be used for enterprise wide companies with lots of traffic?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I know the question is kind of vague, but I need to know why most companies that I have worked for haven't used it. I find it very useful (along with the membership stuff). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not to use Forms auth, or windows auth is highly dependent on your project, its scope and user base.
Your question is very broad, so my answer is as well. Also note that these are not absolute and highly subjective.
Use Forms auth when your use base is external from the enterprise.
Use Windows auth when your company has active directory and its user base is internal.
Use Forms auth if you have a specific set of privileged and the infrastructure guys don't want to add 100 user groups.
Use Windows auth if there are other internal applications and you want to implement Single Signon.
Use forms auth if you want more control over password policies and user registration.
Use Windows auth if your enterprise uses IE, and the users do not want to be prompted for username/password.

Again, highly subjective, and just because you want (for example) Single Sign On doesn't mean you can't use Forms auth. In the end, it just depends.

Comment: I apologize for having the broad question. I wasn't referring to Forms Auth vs Windows Auth (I'm aware and have implemented both), I was more referring to Forms Auth vs custom brewed code for authentication (in a single application, across a server farm, etc...). I'm just puzzled as to why all of the companies that I have worked for have created custom code when they could have just customized the Forms Auth to meet their needs. Is there a security issue? Is it too difficult? Hmmm...

Comment: When you say they wrote custom code, are they still using the membership provider? MS put the membership and role providers in the framework for a reason. I would suggest using what MS has out of the box simply because it has been tested. Personally I implement my own membership provider, derived from their base provider because I don't like storing fields I don't use like password hints and such.

Comment: @Kant:  Coming from the custom-auth-code camp, my opinion is that the out of the box membership provider is too rigid to work in most environments and requires the same amount of time (or more) to implement a custom membership provider that works against your data store versus using what you already have, especially if you already have a good foundation of custom code already developed.

Comment: Thank you. @Jay I was referring to completely custom code (separated from the membership providers, etc...). Thanks @CheckRaise. I do see your point.